# Getting the text inside a range of span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have text in my contenteditable div like this:

```
int main(){
    if( (x>1) && (x<10) )
       statement;
}
```

Its HTML is like this:

```
<div id="board">
   <div>int main<span class="openParen bm1">(</span><span class="closeParen bm1">)</span>{</div>
   <div>if<span class="openParen bm2">(</span> <span class="openParen bm3">(<span>x>1<span class="closeParen bm3">)</span> && <span class="openParen bm4">(</span>x<10<span class="closeParen bm4">)</span> <span class="closeParen bm2">)</span></div>
   <div>statement;</div>
   <div>}</div>
</div>
```

Im on the part where i am looping per row and per column (based on the number of characters found in that row)

```
for(loop for each row){
   for(loop for each character of each 

  //on the part where the kword_search has found 'if'row 

  //therefore im on the 2nd row at the 2nd character(disregarding whitespace)  
     if( /\s+if$/.test(kword_search){

      //How will i get the text within bm2, bm3 and bm4?

     }
   }
}
```

How will i get the text within bm2, bm3 and bm4 I want to access this text so that i can store them into an array like this

```
array[0] = $('.bm2').text(); //((x>1) && (x<10))
array[1] = $('.bm3').text(); //(x>1)
array[2] = $('.bm4').text(); //(x<10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = document.getElementById('board').textContent;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8n5ZR/

---

If you want a more jQuery-ish way, use this:

```
var text = $('#board').text();
```

Comment: 1. i wud like to get the span id of the cond statement if 2. i'd like to get the text of those spans